# How to display values on every first date of every month in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, highcharts, markers

Is there a way to create a chart in highcharts such that it will only display the values that are created in every first day of every month?

I have a planned vs actual series that has daily values (timestamp) in them for 2.5 years.

Now whenever i try to display it in Highcharts, it reads all of the data and displays all of the  spline markers.

What I wanted to do is just filter out and display the values/markers that were created on every first day of the month ex: Jan 1, Feb 1.. etc.

Comment: Can you share what work you have tried to solve your problem?

Comment: Could you reproduce your case with the sample data on some online editor which I could work on? I need to see how your data structure looks like.

Comment: My apologies Im new to highcharts and JS. This is the demo I have been tinkering on: https://jsfiddle.net/Beatles1990/wuc1gryb/7/

Comment: So, as I understood you would like to filter your data and achieve something like I did here: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7Lw938ga/, am I right?

Comment: Exactly what I wanted Sebastian. But I couldn't figure out how to create markers  for all the 1st day of the months when there is no data in the list. For example, in the Actual Series there are no markers for Feb 1 to Apr 1. Is there a way of creating markers in there by just carrying over the value of the previous marker? In this case Jan 1 value will be carried over to Feb 1 - Apr 1?

Comment: @Beatles1990 I think that this calculation should be done on the backend site to avoid unnecessary loading on the browser. But if you want to do it before inserting data to the chart you should loop your data through the years - inside this loop - loop again through the months and if point doesn't exist - add it.